# hardly ever in past simple, Present simple, Present perfect

Tags: adverbs

Can "hardly ever" be used in different tenses, for example, the past simple, present simple, the present perfect, and future simple?

Past simple:

> We hardly ever saw Jim last year.

Present simple:

> He hardly ever eats meat.

Present perfect:

> I've hardly ever left my hometown.

Future simple:

> I'll hardly ever have the chance to see a bafflo.

Comment: All such constructions are fine with ***hardly ever***. Also with functionally similar adverbial elements such as ***never, sometimes, always, occasionally, rarely,*** etc.

Answer (score 2):

In every time presented in this question, **yes**, hardly ever can be used like this.